# Relational query with local storage in Parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have relational query like this

```
PFQuery *query1 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Post"];
[innerQuery whereKeyExists:@"image"];

PFQuery *query2 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Comment"];
[query whereKey:@"post" doesNotMatchQuery:innerQuery];

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *comments, NSError     *error) {
// comments now contains the comments for posts without images
}];
```

I'd like to get it's results from local strage so I'm trying to change code like this, however results are not returned.

```
PFQuery *query1 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Post"];
[innerQuery whereKeyExists:@"image"];
[query1 fromLocalDatastore];

PFQuery *query2 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Comment"];
[query whereKey:@"post" doesNotMatchQuery:innerQuery];
[query2 fromLocalDatastore];

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *comments, NSError     *error) {
// comments now contains the comments for posts without images
}];
```

I've also tried to put only one query either [query1 fromLocalDatastore] or  [query2 fromLocalDatastore] but was not working.

Is there way to get results correctly from local storage with relational query?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you get any success? I've read somewhere, that there is no support for relational queries for the local database, but I can't find the link now.
Met the same problem :)